# Lua metatable, how to forward undefined functions?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I have an empty table which I want to act as a "gateway" to another set of functions at another location.

```
tbl = {}
```

I want to pass called functions from this table to somewhere else as a string:

```
tbl.someMethod("hello")
```

I've tried this with limited success.

```
hand = {
    __index = function(tbl, name)
      hand[name] = function(...) 
          passToSomewhere(name, ...)
      end
    end,
    __call = function(tbl, name, ...)
        hand[name](...)
    end
}
setmetatable(tbl, hand)
tbl.someFunction("hello!", someTbl, someNumber)
```

How do I forward the undefined function through the table without it throwing errors?

Edit: More detail

I'm trying to define and call a function in a table in one call:

```
tbl = {}

hand = {
  __index = function(tbl, name)
    print(name)
    tbl[name] = function(...)
      print(...)
    end
  end
}
setmetatable(tbl, hand)

s,e = pcall(tbl.help,"banana","goat")
print(s)

s,e = pcall(tbl.help,"banana","goat")
print(s)
```

This code does work but the first pcall will throw an error because the function hasn't been defined yet.

Say I wanted to use an library which I know updates quite a lot and keep my script compatible and this library may not be present on my computer. I would like to forward calls to this library across some interface but I still want to be able to call the functions in the same way.

```
--For example I would like to call this function like this:
someLib.doSomething(name, age, telephone)

--Instead of passing it through another function:
someOtherLib.invoke("someLib.doSomething", name, age, telephone)
```

Is this possible?

Edit 2:

Thanks @greatwolf !

This is my working test code.

```
tbl = {}

hand = {
  __index = function(tbl, name)
    tbl[name] = function(...)
      return print(name, ...)
    end
    return rawget(tbl, name) 
  end
}
setmetatable(tbl, hand)

tbl.help("banana","goat")
```

Comment: Maybe you need to `return hand[name]`? Not sure if that's what you're after but if your `__index` doesn't return anything then you end up trying to call `nil` and that will trigger an error.

Comment: Doesn't the simpler `setmetatable(tbl,{__index=othertbl})` work?

Comment: @greatwolf looks like in order to get this to work I need to call the undefined function twice or it won't define. I guess you can't do what I'm trying to do in one go.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @greatwolf Apologies, I've added more detail to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, based on your updated details you want lua to translate this call

```
someLib.doSomething(name, age, telephone)
```

into

```
someOtherLib.invoke("someLib.doSomething", name, age, telephone)
```

behind the scenes. What you have is almost there, you just need to return the newly created function back:

```
__index = function(tbl, name)
  tbl[name] = function(...)
    return someOtherLib.invoke("someLib."..name, ...)
  end
  -- return tbl[name] works too, I used rawget to indicate 
  -- no further __index lookup should be done
  return rawget(tbl, name) 
end
```

Now, if your `someOtherLib` is just a table of functions, lhf's suggestion will work too

```
setmetatable(tbl, {__index = someOtherLib})
```

Now if your `someOtherLib` provides someway to get the function you want to call without actually invoking it just yet, `__index` can relay this without creating extra closure wrappers

```
__index = function(tbl, name)
  tbl[name] = someOtherLib.getFuncByName(name)
  return tbl[name]
end
```

The `__call` metamethod is not needed here.